# React router v6, nested routes with a default path for the parent

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I did not know how to construct the proper question title, sorry for that.
But in a route structure like below, I want the `admin` path to always show `organisations` as the default/index, like whenever you navigate to `/admin`  it automatically navigates to `/admin/organisations`,  but for instance in other path `/admin/users`, or `/admin/organisations/create`  the related components renders.

is such a requirement doable with routes, createBrowserRoute?

```
const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <AppShell />,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        element: <AdminPanel />,
        children: [
          { path: 'organisations', element: <Organisations /> },
          { path: 'users', element: <Users /> }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

currently, I have a `useEffect` in the `AdminPanel` component like

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    if(window.location.pathName === "/admin" ) navigate("/admin/organisations")
},[])
```

But is it doable via react-router props?

I have chosen this structure (*children array*) because all the sub-admin paths should have access to the side menu and according to [react-router official tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#nested-routes) it was the best approach

OBS! index element takes the route/path name of the parent, in my case I wanted the index behavior with a different path name. So it is not considered a duplicate of the flagged question, at least the accepted answer there does not answer my question, though the second answer does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

also you can use this :
[Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wqprth?file=src/index.js)

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <AppShell />,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        element: <AdminPanel />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <Navigate to="/admin/organisations" replace />,
            // when user navigate to /admin it automaticly navigate to /admin/organisations
          },
          { path: 'organisations', element: <Organisations /> },
          { path: 'users', element: <Users /> },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: As I am using a common layout for all children which are rendered as `Outlet` , this answer is the best choice for me

Answer (score 0):

Your AdminPanel may be like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  Navigate,
  Outlet,
  useLocation,
} from 'react-router-dom'

const AdminPanel = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()
  //... you code ...//

  return (
    pathname === '/admin' ? <Navigate to="/admin/organisations" replace /> : <Outlet />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a catch all route and put it at the bottom of the array.

```js
const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <AppShell />,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        children: [
          { path: 'users', element: <Users /> }
          { path: '*', element: <Organisations /> },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

You have 3 options that might help you: `splats` ([link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats)), `basename` ([link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#basename)) and `layout routes`([link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#layout-routes)).

It seams that `/admin` is a layout route that specifies that users might see some sort of dashboard that renders only its contents (common usecase: display a sidebar visible only for the `admins`).

Netherless, you can also use the `<Navigate>` ([link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate)) element to move from one component to another:

```js
const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <AppShell />,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        element: <Navigate to="/admin/organisations" replace/>,
        children: [
          { path: 'users', element: <Users /> }
          { path: 'organisations', element: <Organisations /> },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```